# SQL Query Column with XML Data

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008

I have the following data in a column, how can I query the values inside.

```
<deliveryPart notificationId="12345">
    <message address="email@email.com" content="multipart/alternative" domain="email.com" format="0" id="159436637" recipient-id="098765" targetCode="__MAIN__">
        <custom>
            <recipient Nickname="mynickname" id="54321" />
            <targetData Incident_Id="1509403" reference_nb="0000-0000" />
        </custom>
    </message>
</deliveryPart>
```

I gave it a quick go but I've never done it before and I am in short of time.

```
select top 10 *
from [db].[db].[table]
where mData.value('(deliveryPart/message/recipient-id)[1]','varchar(max)') like '098765'
```

I get the following error

> Msg 4121, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot find either column "mData" or the user-defined function or aggregate "mData.value", or the name is ambiguous.

**UPDATE**

I am using the following code to fetch the xml values and it works

```
SELECT TOP 1000 B1.[mData].value('(deliveryPart/message/@id)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'MessageID', B1.[mData].value('(deliveryPart/message/@address)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS 'Address'
  FROM (SELECT CAST(mData as XML) as xmlData FROM [dbo].[db].[table]) B0
  CROSS APPLY xmlData.nodes('/') B1 (mData)
  WHERE B1.[mData].value('(deliveryPart/message/@address)[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') LIKE '%@%'
```

And it returns the xml values store in the ntext field just fine.

```
180646774   email1@email.com
159436627   test2@hotmail.com
159436637   test3@hotmail.com
```

However, I need to fetch values from outside the mData column and is not letting me do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `@recipient-id` as a XML **attribute** - not XML element:

```
<message address="email@email.com" content="multipart/alternative" 
         domain="email.com" format="0" id="159436637" 
         recipient-id="098765" targetCode="__MAIN__">
         ************  this is an *attribute* - use the `@` to select it!
```

Code:

```
select top 10 *
from [db].[db].[table]
where mData.value('(deliveryPart/message/@recipient-id)[1]', 'varchar(max)') like '098765'
```

Comment: It still returns the same error, the data type of the mData column is ntext.

Comment: @J.D: First of all, `ntext` is deprecated - stop using it. Secondly: if this is **XML** - why aren't you using the `XML` datatype? That's the best suited datatype - and that's the **only** datatype that supports these XQuery expressions ....

Comment: Hi Marc, this came by default with the crm tool, I managed to get some sort of result by casting the column as xml, `SELECT cast(mData as XML).query('deliveryPart/message[@recipient-id="12345"]') as xmlData, *
  FROM [dbo].[data].[table]`